# How to make an image full width in page

Tags: html, css

Hi guys I want to put this part of my website with full width with CSS but I can't find a code that works in that part and I don't understand why.

[image: Where I need Help]

What can I do to make this picture full width?

Comment: Try using `width: 100vw !important;`

Comment: This one didn't work but I fixed already! Thank you for your input

Comment: This question lacks a [mcve] and is not answerable without guesses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this style

```
  .banner_img {
    width: 100vw !important;
    margin-left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
   }
```